# Does try-catch affect threads, COM objects & returned property data

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, com, try-catch

Background: I am trying to offer automation of Outlook **without** referencing the Interop dll. This is to make it easier for clients to install without having to install or reference dlls, in specific folders for the tool.

I am NOT writing the overarching software/tool. So I cannot affect STA/MTA attributes. It is a 3rd party software that allows you to drop in code snippets to form a basic class, and methods etc....

1. If we use Interop dll reference and Early binding, then the following lines work fine:

   ```
   if(item.SenderEmailType == "EX") {
       Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AddressEntry entry = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AddressEntry)item.Sender;
       Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ExchangeUser user = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ExchangeUser)entry.GetExchangeUser();
       row["SenderEmailAddress"] = user.PrimarySmtpAddress;
   } else {
       row["SenderEmailAddress"] = item.SenderEmailAddress;
   }
   ```
2. If we remove the dll Reference, and use dynamic keyword, this piece of code never works, where 'item' is in fact one of a Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem retrieved via the Items.Restrict method:

   ```
   foreach(dynamic item in folderItems) {

   if(item.SenderEmailType == "EX") {
       dynamic entry = item.Sender;
       // the object is always null, as it seems that runtimebinding is not happening properly?
       dynamic user = entry.GetExchangeUser(); 
       // perhaps the COM Object has to attempt to call Outlook, and the info is never returned on the same thread??
       row["SenderEmailAddress"] = user.PrimarySmtpAddress;
   } else {
       // this is OK, as it seems that SenderEmailAddress property data is delivered with the COM Object first time around
       row["SenderEmailAddress"] = item.SenderEmailAddress;  
   }
   }
   ```
3. When the above snippet is wrapped by a ***simple try-catch block***, it works every time. Note that there is NO other difference in code/objects/instance or even email details. The addition of try-catch makes it work - every time. Remove try-catch, and it fails every time.

So the question is, why is this the case, and can i confidently sign off completion of code with the try catch block?

Is this to do with the thread coming back from the COM call being wrapped in try-catch that makes the call come back with results?

I am not familiar enough with the inner workings of COM, so tried looking up some old threads, and there is some hint about threading, COM and runtime binding. But none seem to mention this simple issue of try-catch 'fixing' everything.

Comment: Threads are notoriously good at swallowing Exceptions. Normally you have write really bad exception handling code to mess up. But threads do that by default. Are you properly communicating Exceptions outside of the Thread? If not, you need to do that. Chances are mistakes with *some* Element mess up the whole thread | There are two articles on Exception handling I like to link often, they might help you: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/ | https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET

Comment: do you have a small reproducing project?